# Warning! Legacy WGL is unable to select between different OpenGL versions

Tags: opengl

I was using blender 2.76b on a Windows 7 Ultimate, and nothing really weird showed up when I opened blender and the cmd window appeared, before the blender window appeared.

I updated it to 2.77a, and now in the cmd window, it says:

> Warning! Legacy WGL is unable to select between OpenGL versions.

Is this a big issue that I would want to fix, or would it not matter?

If I should fix it, how should I fix it?

System specs:

Laptop: Samsung Sens R410

OS: Windows 7 Ultimate, was Windows Vista Home Premium OEM (according to the sticker on the underside)

CPU: Intel Pentium Merom T2390 Dual Core 1.87 Ghz

RAM: Installed 5Gb, but can only use 2.75Gb 667 MHz

GPU: ATI Radeon X1250 with 256Mb memory with a weird driver that has OpenGL  issues. The 3d cursor moves when I drag the arrow to move an object in the 3d viewport. I think this is because I am using Vista drivers, and there are no drivers for windows 7.

Comment: The answer is in your own question: ***a weird driver that has OpenGL issues***. Update or fix those issues. Not really a blender problem it seems.

Comment: I know it's not a blender problem, and I can't fix it. I either have to use the generic driver from microsoft or use a vista driver(which I am using), both of which result in crappy performance.

Comment: Have you tried using Linux on that computer? Using a 64 bit version would allow you to use all of your RAM

Comment: I did try fedora 64 bit, but there were opengl issues. My computer teacher(who loves fedora btw) installed it for me, and he gave up on my computer as well.

Comment: ... In that case... look for a new (used?) computer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported this as a bug [here](https://developer.blender.org/T48353), and the answer I got was this:

"Your GPU is too old. You may be able to still use it if you update your drivers."

Comment: This is a non-answer.  My Geforce Nvidia GTX950Ti is *not* too old, and it's using current drivers.

Comment: Well, I have nothing to tell you. That's what one of the blender developers said, not me.

Comment: I found out, for me, the issue was a workaround I tried, that didn't work.  I had left a copy of opengl32.dll in the blender directory.  You might look to see if you have an old copy of an opengl32 library on you system that might be pre-empting your graphics card drivers.

Or if your system is really old, you might want to place an updated opengl32.dll into that directory which 'might' fix the problem.

Comment: I don't have opengl32.dll. There was an old issue where the 3d cursor would move instead of the arrows that move a mesh, and the developers told me to put opengl32.dll in the blender directory. However, it was too laggy, and I deleted it and stuck to hotkeys instead.

Answer (score 0):

That is wild.  I was looking everywhere for the solution to the same issue.  Everywhere mentioned that you had to choose 'integrated graphics' with an Nvidea card.  However I had an AMD card and it was not that old.  The sluggish GUI of Blender was driving me nuts.  It was the latest download (2.79).

Turns out it was because I had issues using 2.78 with remote desktop, due to the version of OpenGL.  I put a 32bit version in the same folder and it would work while using RDP.  When I installed the new Blender, I had not removed that DLL file.  That was it.  I deleted the file and the problem cleared right up!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by following method:
Open windows explorer and type in `%appdata%` find the Blender Foundation folder and delete it.

This might be happened due to some conflict in startup application preference.

Comment: Do note that doing so will delete your startup file, user preferences, and some addons.