# Blender runs slow

Tags: windows, installation

When I reinstall my Win 7 I installed all new drivers and Blender. Firstly Blender didn't work because new version need Service Pack 1 so after few Win Updates Blender starts to run. So I open Blender and I want to do some objects, but Blender was horrible slow! All Blender, from menu to selecting vertex is slow now. But before, I ran Blender 2.78 on the same Win 7 and same specs without problems. When I install fresh OS it's working so slow. I don't know what my PC is missing.

Specs:

Win 7 64-bit

i5 - 4440 3.1GHz

GTX 770 2GB RAM

8GB RAM

and 2.78 Blender runs still slow...

Thanks

**EDIT** 
I'm using Windows 64-bit, and I have Blender installed in the Program Files folder, which is for 64-bit programs. Blender only works if installed in Program Files(x86) I know I downloaded Blender-2.78-windows64.msi, so I don't see why it's doing this.

---

My Win is 64-bit so, I install Blender in Program Files folder, but I think what may happend when I try to install it in Program Files (x86) folder and it's working. But I still don't understand why it was doing this problems, I download blender-2.78-windows64.msi for 64-bit system so why? Thanks for your free time :)

Comment: Is you CPU usage very high? If not then this is probably a graphics driver issue. Try uninstalling them and reinstalling or searching for a newer version or the latest beta.

Comment: I tested now, and CPU was at 48% - 51% of usage. So propably not very high usage, or? I have installed the newest nVidia 375.57 graphic drivers. I tried installed older drivers that I used on my previsious Win and istall back the 375, and few times reinstalling them. Still nothing helps.

Comment: Constant CPU usage that high is not normal  there is something wrong else wrong. Either OpenGL acceleration is not working at all, failing back to software emulation, or its not graphics related. Did you get any command line errors about OpenGL?

Comment: Okay. I get warning from Blender: Legacy WGL is unable to select between OpenGL versions.found bundled python: C:/Program Files/ Blender Foundation/Blender/2.78/python.

Comment: Well there's you issue. Not sure how to solve it exactly but Blender basically can't use your graphics card/drivers. Have you installed new drivers for your graphics card after reinstalling the OS? Do you have the latest version? If not start there.

Comment: The second thing that I installed on new OS was the newest NVIDIA 375.57 graphic drivers using NVIDIA Experience. The 1st thing was Java. So I have already the lastast version of it. Then I try to install old one - I think it was 372.90. They didn't work too, so I install back the 375.57. But the think is, that when I switch to use Intel HD Graphics, Blender still work slow. Any next steps?

Comment: I'm out of options without looking at it. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51905/legacy-wgl-is-unable-to-select-between-opengl-versions-error or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51653/warning-legacy-wgl-is-unable-to-select-between-different-opengl-versions or https://developer.blender.org/T48353 or https://developer.blender.org/T48756

Comment: By the way, thank you very much for your help! I'm really disappointed that Blender won't work normal.

Comment: If nothing else works, try reporting a bug report to the tracker, though I'm not sure about the success. It's weird that it used to work and now no longer works

Comment: I have one more think that I need you to say. If I ran Blender in Full Screen Mode (Alt + F10) The scene start to response faster than like in normal window. And Blender work faster too when I have it in windowed mode on half of my screen. I'll try some fixes and I'll write here if anything helps.

Comment: Yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeaaaaaaaaaah, finallyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy Blender starts to work !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Ouuuuuuuu yeaaaa. Sorry, but I'm happy more than little child. Ouuuu yeeea. My Win is 64-bit so, I install Blender in Program Files folder, but I think what may happend when I  try to install it in Program Files (x86) folder aaaaaaaaaand it's workiiiiing. But I still don't understand why it was doing this problems, I download blender-2.78-windows64.msi for 64-bit system so why? Thanks for your free time.

Comment: I never ever install Blender (or most other applications for that matter) into the system, always use zipped versions in portable mode. Installing to system only ever leads to trouble. Anyway you should post that as an answer bellow, it may help other sin the future. **EDIT:** never mind, just saw you already did.